# How to fetch story_id and user_id from stories tables.

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join, left-join

This is PHP Laravel, SQL LeftJoin query problem. 
I have 2 tables named as, "stories" and "favorite_story". I want to return all values from "stories" table and matched values from "favorite_story" table based on "story_id", which is a common field in both tables.

Result in array form you can see "story_id", "user_id" result are empty, which should not be empty.
Fav_id is empty, which is OKAY because "favorite_story" table is empty.

I want "story_id" to be fetched from stories table and "user_id" to be fetched from "favorite_story" table.

This is my controller code:

```
public function fanfiction(){
    $user_id = Session('userid');
    $data['stories'] =  DB::table('stories')
    ->leftJoin('favorite_story', 'favorite_story.story_id','=','stories.story_id')
    ->Select('*')
    ->get();

    return view('fanfiction', $data);
}
```

This is the result of above code in an array form.

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [story_id] => 
                [story_title] => Third Story
                [story_desc] => This is "Times" story summary.
                [img] => 2018-12-26-70pgFK87ZN.png
                [story_genre] => Fighting
                [story_character] => Aoba Y.
                [story_rating] => Adult Only
                [story_warning] => Drug Use
                [story_date] => December 26, 2018
                [series_id] => 9999999
                [user_id] => 
                [fav_id] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [story_id] => 
                [story_title] => Second Story
                [story_desc] => This is summary of this new story.
                [img] => 2018-12-19-e6JnEpo3ky.jpg
                [story_genre] => Friendship
                [story_character] => Aijsai
                [story_rating] => G
                [story_warning] => Rape (Actual)
                [story_date] => December 19, 2018
                [series_id] => 9999999
                [user_id] => 
                [fav_id] => 
            )
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
public function fanfiction()
{
    $user_id = session->get('userid');

    $data['stories'] =  DB::table('stories')
        ->leftJoin('favorite_story', 'favorite_story.story_id','=','stories.story_id')
        ->select('stories.*') // add other fields that you need from favorite_story table here
        ->get();

    return view('fanfiction', $data);
}
```

The reason this is happening is because, it is taking the `user_id` and `story_id` from the `favorite_story` table which in this case is null.

Comment: I have made some corrections. Your logic really works thank you. But now I am facing another small issue with the same code. I want to show all stories on a webpage, which is showing there but the stories I marked as favorite for more than two users are showing 2 times which shouldn't be. All stories should be shown one time with favorite/unfavorite for a specific logged in user.

Comment: This is the method I used now:


public function fanfiction(){
$user_id = session('userid');
$data['stories'] =  DB::table('stories')
        ->LeftJoin('favorite_story', 'favorite_story.story_id','=','stories.story_id')
        ->Select('favorite_story.user_id', 'stories.story_id', 'stories.story_title', 'stories.story_desc', 'stories.img')
        ->OrderBy('stories.story_id', 'desc')
        ->Get(); 
     return view('fanfiction', $data);
    }

Comment: You could either `groupBy('stories.story_id')` or add `->distinct()->get();`

Comment: groupBy('stories.story_id') shows query exception error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:1055 'narutoworldfanfiction.favorite_story.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `favorite_story`.`user_id`, `stories`.`story_id`, `stories`.`story_title`, `stories`.`story_desc`, `stories`.`img` from `stories` left join `favorite_story` on `favorite_story`.`story_id` = `stories`.`story_id` group by `stories`.`story_id` order by `stories`.`story_id` desc)"

distinct() is showing me a repeated result of stories. I need to put a condition for the user who is logged in based on user_id

Comment: This is result in array form:
[0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [story_id] => 3
)

[1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 3
                    [story_id] => 3
)

if you see both user_id 1 and 3 from favorite_story is showing which should not be, because I want to show favorite_story for the user who is logged in. I hope this array result will help you to understand my problem.

Comment: I tried to put where condition for user who is logged in by this 
->where('favorite_story.user_id', '=', session('userid'))

then it shows the stories which are marked as a favorite by that specific logged-in user but I have to get all favorite (for the logged in user based on user_id from fav_story tbl) and unfavorite stories like all stories from stories table.